# Add LibreOffice dictionary to Pyenchant on Windows for Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, pyenchant

How can I add dictionaries from [github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries) to `pyenchant` on windows for anaconda?

There are similar questions about this on SO, but not for windows:

- [Add dictionary to pyenchant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43932456/5821790) exists, but is for osx users and accepted answer is a dead link.
- [How to add dictionary to PyEnchant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35757407/5821790) is answered for linux/ubuntu users.
- [PyEnchant without German dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11804481/5821790) is answered for linux/ubuntu users.
- [How to download additional dictionaries in pyenchant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40946496/5821790) is answered for linux/ubuntu users.

---

***Background***

> *I've been looking for a way to check if a given string is a valid word of a given language.*

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789057/5821790) and installed `pyenchant` inside the **Anaconda Prompt** successfully (on *Windows 10*) by using `pip` because it [apparently](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyenchant) can't be installed with `conda` for `win-32` nor for `win-64`.

```
  (base) C:\Users\V>pip install pyenchant
    Collecting pyenchant
      Downloading pyenchant-3.2.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (11.9 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 11.9 MB 1.7 MB/s
    Installing collected packages: pyenchant
    Successfully installed pyenchant-3.2.0
```

This worked for me. I can now open Spyder (Python 3.6) and then run

```
import enchant 
print(enchant.list_languages())
```

to see that I have some English dictionaries

```
['en_BW', 'en_AU', 'en_BZ', 'en_GB', 'en_JM', 'en_DK', 'en_HK', 'en_GH', 'en_US', 'en_ZA', 'en_ZW', 'en_SG', 'en_NZ', 'en_BS', 'en_AG', 'en_PH', 'en_IE', 'en_NA', 'en_TT', 'en_IN', 'en_NG', 'en_CA']
```

I would like to have access to languages supported by LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your anaconda package (should be `enchant`).

Inside, find your provider (default should be `hunspell`).

For me, this is at

```
C:\Users\V\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell
```

Now, simply add `.aff` and `.dic` files of the desired language to this `hunspell` folder.

For example, [github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/tree/master/hr_HR](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/tree/master/hr_HR) is for Croatian (Hrvatski).

Then for example,

```
d = enchant.Dict("hr_HR")
print(d.check("mačak"))
```

Returns

```
True
```

as expected. ("mačak" = croatian word for male cat.)